# Authenticating and managing authorization of multiple users simultaneously in django. Both users inheriting from django's AbstractUser class

Tags: reactjs, django-models, django-rest-framework

AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'api.CustomUser'
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'users.Seller'

These are my users and i want both users to be able to perform specific tasks based on permissions.
I am protecting my API views with @permission_classes([IsAuthenticated]). But apparently django uses only one user model at a time for authenticating the logged in user.

I tried custom authentication backends using AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = [ 'yourapp.backends.CustomModelBackend',
'

Comment: I don't really see why you need two user models. The fact that you work with permissions seems to indicate a seller is just a (`Custom`)`User` with certain permissions, which thus means that you cnan make additional checks.